# How does angular render ngFor?

Tags: angular

In particular, does angular apply elements to the DOM in each iteration in `ngFor` or does it wait until `ngFor` finishes and then apply it all (parent) to DOM at once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the source code for [`ngFor`](https://github.dev/angular/angular), this method is called with the changes identified by angular differs, which notifies changes in the object or array. But if you notice the code, **there is a `forEachOperation` which run for each element and inside it we notice for new records, there is a if condition where we run `createEmbeddedView`, so each row is created one by one!**

```
private _applyChanges(changes: IterableChanges<T>) {
    const viewContainer = this._viewContainer;
    changes.forEachOperation(
        (item: IterableChangeRecord<T>, adjustedPreviousIndex: number|null,
         currentIndex: number|null) => {
          if (item.previousIndex == null) {
            // NgForOf is never "null" or "undefined" here because the differ detected
            // that a new item needs to be inserted from the iterable. This implies that
            // there is an iterable value for "_ngForOf".
            viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(
                this._template, new NgForOfContext<T, U>(item.item, this._ngForOf!, -1, -1),
                currentIndex === null ? undefined : currentIndex);
          } else if (currentIndex == null) {
            viewContainer.remove(
                adjustedPreviousIndex === null ? undefined : adjustedPreviousIndex);
          } else if (adjustedPreviousIndex !== null) {
            const view = viewContainer.get(adjustedPreviousIndex)!;
            viewContainer.move(view, currentIndex);
            applyViewChange(view as EmbeddedViewRef<NgForOfContext<T, U>>, item);
          }
        });

    for (let i = 0, ilen = viewContainer.length; i < ilen; i++) {
      const viewRef = <EmbeddedViewRef<NgForOfContext<T, U>>>viewContainer.get(i);
      const context = viewRef.context;
      context.index = i;
      context.count = ilen;
      context.ngForOf = this._ngForOf!;
    }

    changes.forEachIdentityChange((record: any) => {
      const viewRef = <EmbeddedViewRef<NgForOfContext<T, U>>>viewContainer.get(record.currentIndex);
      applyViewChange(viewRef, record);
    });
  }
```

Comment: thanks for this great response and reference! one additional thing, is it possible to circumvent this behavior utilizing manual change detection? so, to mark it as changed only after `ngFor` finished?

Comment: @tlzg You need to enable [`On Push Change Detection`](https://blog.angular-university.io/onpush-change-detection-how-it-works/) after that you can trigger change detection using `this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges()` this will trigger change detection manually, you can wrap it in a setTimeout, but you have never revealed what you actual problem is, like what are you trying to achieve, is it a performance issue?

Comment: Yes of course, i do have `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush`. Yes, I am trying to improve performance as much as possible for cases where I have to render a lot of elements using `ngFor`. (they have to be rendered, there is no way around it)

Comment: The other approach I am exploring is `ng-template` with `templateOutlets` and content projection but I am not sure that's the right way. Manual `detectChanges()` sounds more promising.

Comment: @tlzg it could be not a problem with angular itself, there is a limit to how much DOM the browser can handle, maybe that is the problem, also if there are editable elements on the grid, make them click to edit, but the best solution will be virtual scrolling, try to implement the same, I had the same problem long back, solved it by setting a max limit of number of rows that can be added!

Comment: Yes, I agree with that. All the efforts are in the direction to optimize DOM interventions, not angular side itself. I am just trying to find a way how to control DOM interventions behavior from angular.

Comment: @tlzg [virtual scrolling](https://material.angular.io/cdk/scrolling/overview) that is dom manipulation in angular!

Comment: sure, i did give it a tick already. marking as answer now. Thanks!